# django manage.py custom command not returning output

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to collect my staticfiles with a custom build command in django.

The below is my settings.py(prototypes.py)

```
settings.configure(
DEBUG = True,
ROOT_URLCONF = 'sitebuilder.urls',
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (),
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.webdesign',
'sitebuilder',

),
STATIC_URL='/static/',
SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pages'),
SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_build'),
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_build', 'static'),

)
```

and this is my build.py file

```
def get_pages():
    for name in os.listdir(settings.SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY):
        if name.endswith('.html'):
            yield name[:-5]

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Build static site output.'
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Request pages and build output."""
        if os.path.exists(settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY):
            shutil.rmtree(settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
            os.mkdir(settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
            os.makedirs(settings.STATIC_ROOT)
            call_command('collectstatic', interactive=False,
            clear=True, verbosity=3)
            client = Client()
            for page in get_pages():
                url = reverse('page', kwargs={'slug': page})
                response = client.get(url)
                if page == 'index':
                    output_dir = settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                else:
                    output_dir = os.path.join(settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, page)
                    os.makedirs(output_dir)
                with open(os.path.join(output_dir, 'index.html'), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
```

however , when i run `python prototypes.py build` - python doesnt collect the static files in the build folder.

I'm not getting and errors as such (verbose doesnt seem to help). this is my tree view

```
|-- pages
|   |-- contact.html
|   |-- index.html
|   `-- login.html
|-- prototypes.py
`-- sitebuilder
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- management
    |   |-- commands
    |   |   |-- build.py
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |-- static
    |   |-- css
    |   |-- fonts
    |   `-- js
    |-- templates
    |   |-- base.html
    |   `-- page.html
    |-- urls.py
    `-- views.py
```

Comment: Your code will only run if the `_build` directory exists. Because of the `if` at the very beginning. You probably only intended the `if` to apply to the following line.

Comment: @spectras May be you can post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only run if the _build directory exists. Because of the if at the very beginning.

```
    if os.path.exists(settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY):
        shutil.rmtree(settings.SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
        # [...]
```

You probably only intended the if to apply to the next line, and not your whole function.